# What is wrong with getMonth() + 1;

Tags: javascript, date

I have this code in Sharepoint:

```
     var d = $.trim(oListItem.get_item('Begindatum'));
     alert(d);
     var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
     alert(m);
```

The first alert returns: Thu Apr 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), which is correct.

The second alert (m) is not fired and the code after that is not executed. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Look into the browser console if you see any error

Comment: Your `d` is a string, not a Date object.

Comment: `$.trim()` returns a string

Comment: I guess d is a string not a date

Comment: If you trim something, then it is probably a string value, and not a Date object. Ergo, you can not call Date object methods like getMonth on it. Pretty sure the browser console would’ve already told you something like that, if only you had bothered to look.

Comment: I have no browserconsole. It is blocked in the company where I work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.trim()` will return a string, not a date.

You would need to cast back to a date object before you can do `getMonth()`.

```
 var d = $.trim(oListItem.get_item('Begindatum'));
 alert(d);
 var m = new Date(d).getMonth() + 1;
 alert(m);
```